# Spring Boot application build with Maven encounters Java Version Issue

Tags: java, spring, spring-boot, maven, maven-release-plugin

I was trying to build an application using maven build.It was returning this build failure even though I have placed my pom.xml file is in-place.
I have configure my pom with out any issue.But I can see that there is some error returning related to schema.But don't have much information on that

```
[INFO] Scanning for projects...
[WARNING] 
[WARNING] Some problems were encountered while building the effective model for com.amazon:amazon:jar:0.0.1-SNAPSHOT
[WARNING] 'dependencies.dependency.(groupId:artifactId:type:classifier)' must be unique: org.springframework.boot:spring-boot-starter-test:jar -> duplicate declaration of version (?) @ line 65, column 15
[WARNING] 
[WARNING] It is highly recommended to fix these problems because they threaten the stability of your build.
[WARNING] 
[WARNING] For this reason, future Maven versions might no longer support building such malformed projects.
[WARNING] 
[INFO]                                                                         
[INFO] ------------------------------------------------------------------------
[INFO] Building MyApplication 0.0.1-SNAPSHOT
[INFO] ------------------------------------------------------------------------
[INFO] 
[INFO] --- maven-resources-plugin:3.0.1:resources (default-resources) @ amazon ---
[INFO] Using 'UTF-8' encoding to copy filtered resources.
[INFO] Copying 1 resource
[INFO] Copying 0 resource
[INFO] 
[INFO] --- maven-compiler-plugin:3.7.0:compile (default-compile) @ amazon ---
[INFO] Changes detected - recompiling the module!
[INFO] Compiling 6 source files to /Users/Arun/Documents/SpringBoot/MyApplication/target/classes
[INFO] ------------------------------------------------------------------------
[INFO] BUILD FAILURE
[INFO] ------------------------------------------------------------------------
[INFO] Total time: 3.051 s
[INFO] Finished at: 2018-06-09T08:00:55-07:00
[INFO] Final Memory: 25M/220M
[INFO] ------------------------------------------------------------------------
[WARNING] The requested profile "pom.xml" could not be activated because it does not exist.
[ERROR] Failed to execute goal org.apache.maven.plugins:maven-compiler-plugin:3.7.0:compile (default-compile) on project amazon: Fatal error compiling: invalid target release: 1.8.0_73 -> [Help 1]
[ERROR] 
[ERROR] To see the full stack trace of the errors, re-run Maven with the -e switch.
[ERROR] Re-run Maven using the -X switch to enable full debug logging.
[ERROR] 
[ERROR] For more information about the errors and possible solutions, please read the following articles:
[ERROR] [Help 1] http://cwiki.apache.org/confluence/display/MAVEN/MojoExecutionException
```

Below is the pom.xml which I am using as of now.

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8"?>
<project xmlns="http://maven.apache.org/POM/4.0.0" xmlns:xsi="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema-instance"
    xsi:schemaLocation="http://maven.apache.org/POM/4.0.0 http://maven.apache.org/xsd/maven-4.0.0.xsd">
    <modelVersion>4.0.0</modelVersion>

    <groupId>com.amazon</groupId>
    <artifactId>amazon</artifactId>
    <version>0.0.1-SNAPSHOT</version>
    <packaging>jar</packaging>

    <name>MyApplication</name>
    <description>Demo project</description>

    <parent>
        <groupId>org.springframework.boot</groupId>
        <artifactId>spring-boot-starter-parent</artifactId>
        <version>2.0.2.RELEASE</version>
        <relativePath/> <!-- lookup parent from repository -->
    </parent>

    <properties>
        <project.build.sourceEncoding>UTF-8</project.build.sourceEncoding>
        <project.reporting.outputEncoding>UTF-8</project.reporting.outputEncoding>
        <java.version>1.8.0_73</java.version>
        <start-class>com.amazon.service.MyApplication</start-class>
    </properties>
    <dependencies>
        <dependency>
            <groupId>org.springframework.boot</groupId>
            <artifactId>spring-boot-starter-jersey</artifactId>
        </dependency>
        <dependency>
            <groupId>org.springframework.boot</groupId>
            <artifactId>spring-boot-starter-web</artifactId>
        </dependency>
        <dependency>
            <groupId>org.springframework.boot</groupId>
            <artifactId>spring-boot-starter-web-services</artifactId>
        </dependency>
        <dependency>
            <groupId>org.springframework.boot</groupId>
            <artifactId>spring-boot-starter-webflux</artifactId>
        </dependency>
        <dependency>
            <groupId>org.springframework.data</groupId>
            <artifactId>spring-data-rest-hal-browser</artifactId>
        </dependency>
        <!-- https://mvnrepository.com/artifact/org.apache.tomcat.embed/tomcat-embed-jasper -->
        <dependency>
            <groupId>org.apache.tomcat.embed</groupId>
            <artifactId>tomcat-embed-jasper</artifactId>
            <scope>provided</scope>
        </dependency>
        <dependency>
            <groupId>org.springframework.boot</groupId>
            <artifactId>spring-boot-starter-test</artifactId>
            <scope>test</scope>
        </dependency>
        <dependency>
            <groupId>io.projectreactor</groupId>
            <artifactId>reactor-test</artifactId>
            <scope>test</scope>
        </dependency>
        <!-- https://mvnrepository.com/artifact/org.springframework.boot/spring-boot-starter-test -->
        <dependency>
            <groupId>org.springframework.boot</groupId>
            <artifactId>spring-boot-starter-test</artifactId>
        </dependency>
        <dependency>
            <groupId>org.springframework.restdocs</groupId>
            <artifactId>spring-restdocs-mockmvc</artifactId>
            <scope>test</scope>
        </dependency>
        <!-- https://mvnrepository.com/artifact/org.springframework.boot/spring-boot-starter-data-jpa -->
        <dependency>
             <groupId>org.springframework.boot</groupId>
             <artifactId>spring-boot-starter-data-jpa</artifactId>
        </dependency>

    </dependencies>

    <build>
        <plugins>
            <plugin>
                <groupId>org.springframework.boot</groupId>
                <artifactId>spring-boot-maven-plugin</artifactId>
            </plugin>
        </plugins>
    </build>


</project>
```

Answer (score 1):

According to your logs:

```
Fatal error compiling: invalid target release: 1.8.0_73
```

You might be using an inferior JDK version (1.7 for example) to compile your project to a higher target version (1.8.0_73 in your case).

Try installing JDK 1.8 and make your `JAVA_HOME` environment variable point to it.

Generally you should make sure the source JDK and target JDK are matching between your `pom.xml` file and your `JAVA_HOME` environment variable.

Comment: This is the version in my local Aruns-MBP:~ ArunMannuru$ java -version
java version "1.8.0_73"
Java(TM) SE Runtime Environment (build 1.8.0_73-b02)
Java HotSpot(TM) 64-Bit Server VM (build 25.73-b02, mixed mode)  I have given same <java.version>1.8.0_73</java.version> version in pom.xml as well.

Comment: That means your using JDK 1.8 to compile your project. Could you share your pom.xml file on the other hand?

Comment: <java.version>1.8.0_73</java.version>
   This is what I have configure in my pom.xml

Comment: Is that what you are looking for ??

Comment: It would be more helpful though to update your question with the whole pom file and what maven commands you are executing.

Comment: @user1918566 what is the value of your JAVA_HOME variable?

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](https://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/172818/discussion-between-user1918566-and-n-labrahmi).

Answer (score 0):

You can try maven compiler plugin

```
<build>
    <plugins>
        <plugin>
            <groupId>org.apache.maven.plugins</groupId>
            <artifactId>maven-compiler-plugin</artifactId>
            <version>3.6.1</version>
            <configuration>
                <source>1.8</source>
                <target>1.8</target>
            </configuration>
        </plugin>
    </plugins>
</build>
```

Comment: This is not needed cause this is already done in Spring Boot parents...

Answer (score 0):

Remove the duplicate dependency added

```
        <artifactId>spring-boot-starter-test</artifactId>
```

And 
Try pointing to  JDK 1.8 in project build path and make your JAVA_HOME environment to this

Answer (score 0):

In general the minor release number (for java) is not configured in pom.xml. Only major release number will be require.
Try to change **1.8.0_73** to **1.8**.

To understand the java version system please visit this [link](http://www.oracle.com/technetwork/java/javase/versioning-naming-139433.html).

Answer (score 0):

Looking in your maven output, it is clear that you have a duplicate dependency declaration. Moreover, it is clear that the duplicate dependency is the `org.springframework.boot:spring-boot-starter-test`.

What is the process of solving the issue and removing this WARNING:

1. Look **VERY** carefully your pom.xml. You probably have declared the dependency twice.
2. An other cause of this warning might be that a dependency is declared twice, but with different versions. The solution, again, is to delete the dependency for one of them.
3. Command `mvn dependency:tree -Dverbose` might be useful.

Finally, after writing the above process, I looked in the pom.xml file you posted in your question and found that you have declared the following dependency twice (line:54 and line:65).

```
<dependency>
    <groupId>org.springframework.boot</groupId>
    <artifactId>spring-boot-starter-test</artifactId>
</dependency>
```

As far as I am concerned, this library is used for testing purposes only. If this is true, depending on your requirements, you should keep only the dependency in line 54 and the warning will be removed.